# Relative link from IFrame to navigate parent page and open new tab/window

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

Is it possible to create a relative link within an IFrame `www.frame.com` which satisfies the following requirements:

- The link should navigate the parent page `www.parent.com`
- The link should be relative to the parent page: The link `foo/bar` should open `www.parent.com/foo/bar`
- Link should open in new tab/window

I'm aware of `target="_parent"` or `target="_top"` but that prevents me from using `target="_blank"` to open in new tab/window.

Also relative links open on the parent page with the URL relative to the IFrame. E.g. `www.frame.com/foo/bar` is opened on the parent page instead of `www.parent.com/foo/bar`...

The IFrame is on a different domain so I can't use JS like `window.parent.open(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible you can use [Base](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) html tag for achieving this scenario. On frame page give base tag with href "www.parent.com" and vice versa for the parent page!